# output for 3 aggregated column through one query

Tags: teradata

I want to calculate the business days for 3 columns with respective columns.
Eg:

1. `REC_ENTER_BUSS_DAY` will calculate the business day between `REC_CREATED_DATE` and `ENTER_DATE`.
2. `REC_SCAN_BUSS_DAY` will calculate between `REC_CREATED_DATE` and `SCAN_DT`
3. `INDX_BUS_DAY` between `REC_CREATED_DATE` and `INDX_DT`.

I have calendar table having business day indicator `BUS_DT_IND='Y'` and `'N'`.

I want output for all three port at a time.

Any one help me out with query.

```
Select A.REC_ENTR_B_DY
     , B.REC_SCAN_B_DY
     , C.INDX_B_DY 
  from (select ENTR_DT
             , REC_CREATED_DT
             , SUM(WHEN BUS_DT_IND='Y' then 1 else 0) as REC_ENTR_B_DY 
          from RECORD 
          join calendar 
            on calendar.Calendar_date between ENTR_DT and REC_CREATED_DT 
         group by 1,2) A 
    LEFT JOIN (select SCAN_DT
                          , REC_CREATED_DT
                          , SUM(WHEN BUS_DT_IND='Y' then 1 else 0) as REC_SCAN_B_DY 
                       from RECORD 
                       join calendar on calendar.Calendar_date between SCAN_DT and REC_CREATED_DT 
                      group by 1,2) B 
           on A.REC_CREATED_DT=B.REC_CREATED_DT 
    LEFT JOIN (select INDX_DT
                    , REC_CREATED_DT
                    , SUM(WHEN BUS_DT_IND='Y' then 1 else 0) as REC_SCAN_B_DY 
                 from RECORD 
                 join calendar 
                   on calendar.Calendar_date between INDX_DT and REC_CREATED_DT
                group by 1,2)C 
           on A.REC_CREATED_DT=C.REC_CREATED_DT
```

Comment: Do you have any sample SQL that didn't produce the expected outcome?

Comment: i have done this by self join.

Select A.REC_ENTR_B_DY, B.REC_SCAN_B_DY, C.INDX_B_DY
from
(select ENTR_DT, REC_CREATED_DT, SUM(WHEN BUS_DT_IND='Y' then 1 else 0) as REC_ENTR_B_DY from RECORD join calendar on calendar.Calendar_date between ENTR_DT and  REC_CREATED_DT
group by 1,2)A


LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select SCAN_DT, REC_CREATED_DT, SUM(WHEN BUS_DT_IND='Y' then 1 else 0) as REC_SCAN_B_DY from RECORD join calendar on calendar.Calendar_date between SCAN_DT and  REC_CREATED_DT
group by 1,2)B
on A.REC_CREATED_DT=B.REC_CREATED_DT

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN
(select INDX_DT, REC_CREATED_DT, SUM(WHEN BUS_DT_IND='Y' then 1 else 0) as REC_SCAN_B_DY from RECORD join calendar on calendar.Calendar_date between INDX_DT and  REC_CREATED_DT
group by 1,2)C
on A.REC_CREATED_DT=C.REC_CREATED_DT

Comment: This query is taking time. because we have approx 30 million records

Comment: Of course this results in a huge intermediate results, what's the average number of days between start and end date? And then you join on a non-unique column...

Comment: Not sure I follow your logic, but couldn't you just join `records` to `calendar`  3 times in one query, instead of all the self joins on your giant table?